# Fixed SVG height & variable (100%) width

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to put a svg object on my html page and I want it to have a 100% width and a fixed height.

In my fiddle you can see that the height of the dark-grey object changes according to the window proportions. (This is not what I want)

http://jsfiddle.net/Lq207ery/6/

HTML

```
<body>
<!-- HEADER -->
<header>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="triangle">
        <svg data-type="vertical_parallax" data-speed="2" x="0px" y="0px" width="410" height="410" viewBox="0 0 310 310" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
            <g>
                <!--<polyline stroke="#222" fill="none" stroke-width="1" points="0,210 0,210 310,0 "></polyline>-->
                <polyline fill="#CC0000" points="0,0 0,200 300,0    "></polyline>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYmin">
            <polygon fill="#222" stroke-width="0" points="0,1.5 0,0 10,0 15,0 " />
        </svg>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- CONTENT -->
```

CSS

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
header svg {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
header .triangle {
    z-index: 200;
}
header .logo {
    margin-top: -90px;
}
header .nav {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Give your SVG element a fixed height. If you do not do this the height of the element will change proportional to the width.
2. Adjust your `viewBox` to crop to the height of your content.
3. Fix your `preserveAspectRatio` value to have the proper case-sensitive value, e.g. `xMinYMin` (not `xMinYmin`).

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq207ery/8/

If you want your dark grey triangle to stretch (not preserving its aspect ratio) then instead use `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq207ery/9/

Comment: Thank you Phrogz, the "preserveAspectRatio" method is what I was looking for. 
I've tried it before but the svg css changes do the trick.

Comment: You're welcome! In the future, please try to remember to not only show what is wrong (which you did perfectly) but to also describe clearly what you want/expect instead. It was not clear to me exactly what you wanted the final appearance to be.

Answer (score 1):

You explanation is somewhat short, but you could do it like this :

**HTML Code :**

```
<header>
    <div class="triangle">
        <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="410" height="410" viewBox="0 0 310 310">
            <g>
                <polyline fill="#CC0000" points="0,0 0,200 300,0"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="nav"></div>
</header>
```

**CSS Code :**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
header {
    position: relative;
}
header .triangle {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;        
}
header .nav {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 2000px; // big screens
    height: 100px;
    background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20width%3D%22150px%22%20height%3D%2215px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20150%2015%22%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpolygon%20fill%3D%22%23222%22%20points%3D%220%2C15%200%2C0%20100%2C0%20150%2C0%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom left;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**SVG before url encoding :**

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="150px" height="15px" viewBox="0 0 150 15">
    <g>
        <polygon fill="#222" points="0,15 0,0 100,0 150,0"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/sparkup/21uaffpy/

Or line this maybe : http://jsfiddle.net/sparkup/21uaffpy/18/

Comment: Thank you Sparkup, I might use this trick for another project. How do you get the background-image:url(....) ?

Comment: You just urlencode `<svg>...</svg>` with `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition I'd like to add If the svg has the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` all set, another place possibility is to use a container div and `font-size` something like:

```
        <div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; fontSize: 50px">
           <svg>...</svg>
        </div>
```